# Output the id of a specific <td>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I need to create a function that outputs only the id of any image whenever the user click on it. (Javascript or jQuery it doesn't matter)

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td id="1"><img src="image1.gif"></td>  
    <td id="2"><img src="image1.gif"</td>
    <td id="3"><img src="image1.gif"</td>           
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Your images don't have IDs. Do you mean the ID of the parent cell? Also, what have you tried?

Comment: yea...id of <td>s indeed

Comment: And for greatest compatibility, IDs should not start with a number even though HTML5 allows this.

Comment: Please go through your previous questions and mark some answers. I pains me to see your history in such a state! http://stackoverflow.com/users/1993051/paul-g-nahed?tab=questions

Comment: Also, your image tags for the 2nd and 3rd image are not closed.

Comment: dear @Codesleuth :)im very new here...im sorry if im not acting properly ... I just need some help for my university project thats all

and guys i know i did many typing faults and missing many character but please i need an answer not only correcting faults

thnk u

Comment: You have plenty of answers to your questions. This community thrives on its reputation system, and will be more likely to continue helping you if you take the time to give reputation in the form of upvotes or accepting answers to your questions. Please refer to the FAQ for more information on how to use this site: http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a class to your table:

```
<table class="tblImages">
  <tr>
    <td id="1"><img src="image1.gif"></td>  
    <td id="2"><img src="image1.gif"</td>
    <td id="3"><img src="image1.gif"</td>           
  </tr>
</table>
```

Then delegate the binding:

```
$('.tblImages').on('click', 'td', function(e){ 
    var id = this.id; // here you go
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Uz2pW/

Comment: I wouldn't name a variable 'id' though, just for the sake of keeping everything straight.

Comment: ive checked..the demo is working
this is what i posted in my file..

<table class="tblImages">
  <tr>
    <td id="1"><img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/e/ec/Soccer_ball.svg/50px-Soccer_ball.svg.png"></td>  
    <td id="2"><img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/e/ec/Soccer_ball.svg/50px-Soccer_ball.svg.png"></td>
    <td id="3"><img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/e/ec/Soccer_ball.svg/50px-Soccer_ball.svg.png"></td>           
  </tr>
</table>
<script>
$('.tblImages').on('click', 'td', function(e){ 
    alert(this.id);
});
</script>

Comment: Are you including jQuery in your page?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("td img").on("click", function() {
    var id = $(this).closest("td").attr("id");
    // do as you want with id
});
```

Answer (score 0):

None of your images have id's, but you can get the id of the table cell:

```
$('image').click(function(){
    var parentID = $(this).closest('td').id;
    console.log(parentID);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$('td').on('click', function(){
   alert($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

***[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/V9Hbu/)***

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for printing the data cell id wrapping the image, then one option is to attach an id for each image that would enable you to retrieve its parent node from javascript. It would look like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function say_id(some_id) {
    alert(document.getElementById(some_id).parentNode.id);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<table>
<tr>
    <td id="1"><img id="img-1" src="Tulips.jpg" onclick="say_id(this.id)"/></td>  
    <td id="2"><img id="img-2" src="Tulips.jpg" onclick="say_id(this.id)"/></td>
    <td id="3"><img id="img-3" src="Tulips.jpg" onclick="say_id(this.id)"/></td>           
</tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```